# Error con un procedimineto PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

estoy intentando crear este procedimiento, pero me devuelve un error, como vereis despues me dice que debo declarar algunas variables, pero no entiendo el porque y tampoco se como hacerlo.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CALCULAR_SUELDO_DEPAR(
        P_COD_DEP IN N_DEPARTAMENTOS.COD_DEP%TYPE, P_TOTAL_SUELDO OUT NUMBER)
    AS
        DEP_VALIDO NUMBER(3);
        EXISTE_EMPLEADO NUMBER(3);
        SUELDO_BRUTO NUMBER (10);
        SUELDO_TOTAL NUMBER (10);

        NO_EXISTE_DEPARTAMENTO EXCEPTION;
        NO_HAY_EMPLEADOS_DEPART EXCEPTION;
        NO_HAY_EMPLEADOS_CURSOR EXCEPTION;
    BEGIN

    -- BUSCO EL DEPARTAMENTO
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO DEP_VALIDO
        FROM N_DEPARTAMENTOS
        WHERE COD_DEP = P_COD_DEP;

    -- BUSCO EMPLEADOS EN EL DEPARTAMENTO
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO EXISTE_EMPLEADO
        FROM N_EMPLEADOS
        WHERE COD_DEP = P_COD_DEP;

    -- EVALUO SI EL DEPARTAMENTO ES VÁLIDO
    IF DEP_VALIDO = 0 THEN
        RAISE NO_EXISTE_DEPARTAMENTO;
        P_TOTAL_SUELDO := -1;

    -- EVALUO SI HAY EMPLEADOS
    ELSIF EXISTE_EMPLEADO = 0 THEN
        RAISE NO_HAY_EMPLEADOS_DEPART;
        P_TOTAL_SUELDO := -2;

    ELSE
        FOR V_CURSOR IN (SELECT EMP.NRO_HIJOS, EMP.DNI, EMP.NRO_TRIENIOS, NIV.SUELDO_BASE, NIV.EUROS_UN_TRIENIO
                            FROM N_EMPLEADOS EMP INNER JOIN N_NIVELES NIV
                            ON EMP.COD_NIVEL = NIV.COD_NIVEL
                            WHERE SUMA_COMPLEMENTOS(EMP.DNI) > 250
                            AND COD_DEP = P_COD_DEP) LOOP
        SUELDO_BRUTO := (NIV.SUELDO_BASE + NRO_TRIENIOS * NIV.EUROS_UN_TRIENIO + SUMA_COMPLEMENTOS(EMP.DNI));
        SUELDO_TOTAL := SUELDO_BRUTO - (SUELDO_BRUTO * CALCULAR_IRPF(EMP.NRO_HIJOS, EMP.SUELDO_BASE));
        P_TOTAL_SUELDO := P_TOTAL_SUELDO + SUELDO_TOTAL;
        END LOOP;
    END IF;


    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_EXISTE_DEPARTAMENTO THEN
            P_TOTAL_SUELDO := -1;
        WHEN NO_HAY_EMPLEADOS_DEPART THEN
            P_TOTAL_SUELDO := -2;
        WHEN NO_HAY_EMPLEADOS_CURSOR THEN
            P_TOTAL_SUELDO := -3;
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CÓDIGO :'|| SQLCODE || ' ERROR : '||SQLERRM);
    END CALCULAR_SUELDO_DEPAR;
```

Cuando lo compilo me devuelve el siguiente error, no entiendo porque luego me pide que declare esas dos y luego otras no, he probado muchas cosas pero cada vez la lio mas, este código creo que es lo mas limpio que he podido sacar.

```
Procedure CALCULAR_SUELDO_DEPAR compilado

LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
40/5      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
40/22     PLS-00201: identifier 'NIV.SUELDO_BASE' must be declared
41/5      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
41/66     PLS-00201: identifier 'EMP.NRO_HIJOS' must be declared
Errores: comprobar log de compilador
```

Answer (score 3):

Dentro del `FOR` del cursor implícito no aplican los alias de tablas y debes usar la referencia del cursor:

En lugar de `NIV.SUELDO_BASE` usa `V_CURSOR.SUELDO_BASE`.

```
SUELDO_BRUTO := (V_CURSOR.SUELDO_BASE + V_CURSOR.NRO_TRIENIOS * V_CURSOR.EUROS_UN_TRIENIO + SUMA_COMPLEMENTOS(V_CURSOR.DNI));
```

Comment: Ahora me compila sin problemas, pre no me calcula nada, si saco el select fuera del cursor y lo pruebo si me da resultado dependiendo del departamento que le ponga, pero en el cursor, no, alguna idea?

Comment: Revisa inicialización de variables y si `SUMA_COMPLEMENTOS` regresa `NULL`. Recuerda que `NULL+1=NULL`, para algunos casos puedes apoyarte de las funciones `nvl()`y `coalesce()`.